# Laying a coordinate system using several markers

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing a marker based AR application with Vuforia in Unity 3D. I want to lay a coordinate system in a room with 4 unique markers on the walls so that I can place 3D objects on the floor of the room.

The camera may not be able to see the markers all the time. But the coordinate system should be persistent and should use motion/orientation sensors of the device to offer the user uninterrupted AR experience. As soon as the camera recognizes a marker, the coordinate system should be recalibrated.

I'm new to Vuforia, so can you please suggest a way I can achieve this kind of behavior? Does Vuforia support this kind of behavior out of the box?

Thank you.

### Edit:  Evert

**After reading the comment from Evert, I realized I can use *marker less* AR to fill the gaps between *marker based* detection.**

Now I'm curious to know how I can achieve that. Please help :)

Thank you.

Comment: Simply said, no. The part about using gyro and accelerometer to move around is way beyond your scope (or you have a phd in algebra?). But the good news, you may want to look into ArKit and ArCore. They may solve your issue without marker.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Everts. I updated the question.

Comment: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/02/16/developing-for-arkit-1-5-update-using-unity-arkit-plugin/  https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/02/23/arcore-1-0-for-unity-is-here-start-building/